# Usage and meaning of "manger/boire en suisse"

Tags: sens, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

I have seen "manger/boire en suisse" listed as an idiom to mean to eat/drink alone.

My question(s):

- Is "manger/boire en suisse" an idiom that is still in use today?
- Could this idiom also be mistaken to mean: eat/drink in Swiss?

Answer (score 4):

It's quite an old expression and is seldom used nowadays.
It comes from a cultural difference: When among friends in public places (bar, pub...) the French often, in turn, "paie la tournée" - pay a round. When in the Germanic cultures each pay for his own drinks as a more general rule.

Comment: More here http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/boire-faire-quelque-chose-en-suisse.php

Answer (score 0):

"Manger/boire en suisse" refers to the Vatican Swiss Guards who had to eat/drink standing (alone) while on their watch guard.  - Hussein FAKHRY

Comment: According to what sources? Because [this is contradicted by other sources](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/boire-faire-quelque-chose-en-suisse.php) that do not mention the Vatican Swiss Guards.